# Difference in eigenvalue equations

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I came across a strange equation in the solution to a problem. It looks like this:$$My - Mx = \lambda x$$

In this problem $M$ is an $n\times n$ (full rank) matrix, and $x$ and $y$ are vectors. ($y$ is given in the problem and I am looking for $x$). Is there a solution for $x$ here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $M+\lambda$ is invertible. Then
$$
My = (M+\lambda)x 
$$
which means that
$$
(M+\lambda)^{-1} M y  = x
$$
which would then directly give you $x$ if you know $y,\lambda, M$.

Comment: Presumably $\lambda$ is a number, not a matrix, so it should be $M + \lambda I$.

Comment: @Théophile "scalar" is more precise; matrices are members of a ring, and therefore are "numbers" in a broad sense.

Comment: @Acccumulation Some kind of tiny alarm was going off in my head as I wrote that, but I wasn't sure why... Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 5):

Rearrange the equation as $y=(\lambda M^{-1}+I)x$. Therefore it is solvable if and only if $y$ lies inside the range of $\lambda M^{-1}+I$, i.e. if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(\lambda M^{-1}+I)=\operatorname{rank}\pmatrix{\lambda M^{-1}+I&y}$.

Comment: y is given. It's x that's being asked to solve for.